# How do you generate a base58 private key?

Tags: keypair

I know how to [generate a keypair](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-new-keypair) that has the uint8Array private key and [generate a mnemonic](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase), but how do you generate a base58 private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the base58 private key with the following code in js:

```
var web3 = require('@solana/web3.js')
var bs58 = require('bs58')

let keypair = web3.Keypair.generate()
let base58PrivateKey = bs58.encode(result.secretKey)
```

Running this with `node <FILENAME>.js` will generate the private key and encode it with base58 at the variable `base58PrivateKey`.